# Problems in using the user-provided values of headers in wget command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, wget

I am writing a simple bash shell script; which outputs the page-load time of url. The server responds with correct page only when it is requested with specific custom headers (FYI: absence of headers the default page is served by server. ) 
The url to visit & its headers are read from a config file (delimited by semi-colon)
Sample entry: http://google.com/;User-Agent:XYZ A;msisdn:98xxxxxxxx

I did everything from reading the file to firing the wget command.

However, looking at the output I found out that, headers string is not correctly passed (though I am building it correctly) to the wget command.
On debugging further, I found out that bash/linux in-tern wrapping the whole headers string into single quotes and sending it to wget command due to which the wget is failing to give me the expected output.

The code:

```
#!/bin/bash
load_page()
{
    echo "url=$url";
    echo "headers=$header_str";
    /usr/bin/time -f "\t%e\t%C" wget -kKHpq --no-cache "$header_str" "$url" 
}
read_config_file()
{
    while read cfg_line
    do
        if [[ ! "$cfg_line" = \#* ]] && [[ "x$cfg_line" != "x" ]] ; then    
            url=`echo $cfg_line | cut -d";" -f1`
            fields=`echo $cfg_line | awk -F";" ' { print NF } ' `; 
            f_cnt=2;
            unset header_str
            while [ $f_cnt -le $fields ] ; 
            do
                field=`echo $cfg_line | cut -d";" -f$f_cnt`;
                header_name=`echo $field | cut -d":" -f1`;
                header_val=`echo $field | cut -d":" -f2`;
                header_str="${header_str}--header=\"${header_name}: $header_val\" "
                f_cnt=`expr $f_cnt + 1`;
            done
            load_page 
        fi
    done<urls.cfg   
}
main()
{
    read_config_file
}
main $@
```

The output:

```
url=http://some-website.com/

headers=--header="User-Agent: XYZ G" --header="msisdn: 98xxxxxxxx" 

6.37    wget -kKHpq --no-cache --header="User-Agent: XYZ G" --header="msisdn: 98xxxxxxxx"  http://some-website.com/
```

Every thing looks fine however no proper page is fetched. If I copy paste the command from output then server responds with expected page.

when ran shell script in debug mode ; I think this is the problem. The headers string is getting wrapped into the single quotes in wget command.

please help.

```
+ load_page
+ echo url=http://some-website.com/
url=http://some-website.com/
+ echo 'headers=--header="User-Agent: XYZ G" --header="msisdn: 98xxxxxxxx" '
headers=--header="User-Agent: XYZ G" --header="msisdn: 98xxxxxxxx" 
+ /usr/bin/time -f '\t%e\t%C' wget -kKHpq --no-cache '--header="User-Agent: XYZ G" --header="msisdn: 98xxxxxxxx" ' http://some-website.com/
    1.66    wget -kKHpq --no-cache --header="User-Agent: XYZ G" --header="msisdn: 98xxxxxxxx"  http://some-website.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the use of `eval`. To do so, you would build up up the full command as a string that would be passed to `eval`. I am not at a place to write out a full example with wget, but the basic idea would be:

```
my_args='-al'
eval "ls ${my_args}"
```

If you work up from this basic example, I think you will find you can reliably combine the fixed aspects of your command with the user strings from your config.

For small but informative on discussion on the use of `eval`, `exec` and `source`, I recommend you read this thread on [bash shell: 'exec', 'eval', 'source' - looking for help to understand](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/54347-bash-shell-exec-eval-source-looking-help-understand.html)

Comment: Thank you sor much.  It worked. Here is the changed command `wget_cmd="/usr/bin/time -f \"\t%e\t%C\" wget -kKHpq --no-cache $header_str $url
eval "$wget_cmd"`

Comment: @OceanBlue I am glad it worked for you. I would caution you that user-supplied values need some careful checking before being handed to `eval`. For that reason, there are many that would recommend against it. Being a pragmatist, I  think there is a time and place for a quick and dirty Bash script to get done what you need. At the same time, it is important to realize that if this script is being used on a sensitive system or executed by a user with escalated privileges or the user-provided values come from an untrusted source, then it is wise and appropriate to carefully consider alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are quoting the string, what happens if you remove the quotes?

```
/usr/bin/time -f "\t%e\t%C" wget -kKHpq --no-cache $header_str "$url"
```

Anything quoted should be passed along as a single parameter (string). so if its unquoted, it should evaluate and pass them as separate parameters

Comment: Tried it.      <br/> But it gives errors and I think without (double) quotes the `$header_str`  is broken into different parameters (separated by spaces) which the wget command itself does not understand. `+ /usr/bin/time -f '\t%e\t%C' wget -kKHpq --no-cache '--header="User-Agent:' XYZ 'G"' '--header="msisdn:' '98xxxxxxxx"' http://some-website.com/
Command exited with non-zero status 4`

Answer (score 0):

`$header_str` is interpreted as a single argument because it is wrapped in quotes.

Try changing your wget command to:

```
 /usr/bin/time -f "\t%e\t%C" wget -kKHpq --no-cache $header_str "$url"
```

Even though the output says:

```
wget -kKHpq --no-cache --header="User-Agent: XYZ G" --header="msisdn: 98xxxxxxxx"  http://some-website.com/
```

the arguments are being passed to the process's `argv` array will look something like this:

```
[ "wget", "-kKHpq", "--no-cache"  "-header=\"User-Agent: XYZ G\" --header=\"msisdn: 98xxxxxxxx\", "http://some-website.com/" ]
```

Comment: Tried it. but it gives errors and I think without (double) quotes the `$header_str`  is broken into different parameters (separated by spaces) which the wget command itself does not understand. `+ /usr/bin/time -f '\t%e\t%C' wget -kKHpq --no-cache '--header="User-Agent:' XYZ 'G"' '--header="msisdn:' '98xxxxxxxx"' http://some-website.com/
Command exited with non-zero status 4`